# No instance of function template matches the argument list, argument types are: (std::string, CommandLineArgumentTypes)

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, template-argument-deduction

I have a function template that takes a `std::string` and an `enum` value that describes the type of data contained within the string. It converts the string into and returns a `std::string`, `int`, `unsigned int`, or `bool` depending on the `enum` value.

```
template <typename T> T parseInput(std::string &input, CommandLineArgumentTypes &type) {
    switch (type) {
        case CommandLineArgumentTypes::String :
            return input;
        case CommandLineArgumentTypes::Int :
            if (int value = std::stoi(input)) {
                return value;
            }

            if (input.size() > 1) {
                if (input[0] == "0" && input[1] == "x") {
                    if (int value = std::stoi(input.substr(1, input.size() - 2))) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            }

            return NULL;
        case CommandLineArgumentTypes::UInt :
            return (unsigned int)std::stoi(input);
        case CommandLineArgumentTypes::Flag :
            return true;
    }
}
```

When I make a call to the function template

```
parseInput(arg, type);
```

where `arg` is a string and `type` is `CommandLineArgumentTypes`, I get the error

> `no instance of function template matches the argument list, argument types are: (std::string, CommandLineArgumentTypes)`.

How can I get the template to determine the return type, why does this error occur when the arguments do match the argument list, and what is a better way to do this?

Comment: The return type has to be known at compile time, and it must be a fixed type. You can make the function template take `type` as a template parameter, and then use `if constexpr` to branch appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. the template argument `T` isn't deducible from the type of the arguments (`input` and `type`).

I understand that your intention is deduce it from the **value** of the type, but this, simply, doesn't works in C++.

You have to explicit it, calling the function; by example

```
 parseInput<bool>(arg, type);
```

2. your function has different `return`s with different types. And they are incompatibles.

Before C++17 (before `if constexpr`) this can't be done.

In C++17, it can be done, (with `if constexpr`, not with `switch`) but only if the test is based on a compile-time known value.

So, if you pass `type` as template parameter (if you know its value compile-time, obviously) you can write something as (caution: code not tested)

```
template <CommandLineArgumentTypes type>
auto parseInput (std::string &input)
 {
   if constexpr ( CommandLineArgumentTypes::String == type )
       return input;
   else if constexpr ( CommandLineArgumentTypes::Int == type )
    {
      // do something else
    }
   else if constexpr ( CommandLineArgumentTypes::UInt == type )
      return (unsigned int)std::stoi(input);
   else if constexpr ( CommandLineArgumentTypes::Flag == type )
      return true;
   // else ?
}
```

The call become, by example,

```
 parseInput<CommandLineArgumentTypes::UInt>(arg);
```

but, I repeat, this can works only if the template argument (the old `type`) is known compile type.

Comment: Calling the template function explicitly is what I was wondering how to do. Is there any easy way to set `type` based on the enumeration?

Comment: @TwistyTurtleFish - not sure to understand your question... answer modified (at the final example) to make it clearer a point; hope this helps.